# How to include .config file or a dependency project in to bin folder of a main project?

Tags: c#, build, localization, application-settings

I have a business project that contains code for business rules, in this project I have setting file storing the message for exception ( to avoid hard coding).

In UI project, I refer to business project and UI project has a method throws exception which has exception message defined in business project.

But after build, I can not find the Business.config because it didn't copy to the UI bin folder.

**So how to include business setting/config file in to UI project?**

I figure out that whole the application setting section is included in the Business.dll file.
This way I can not change the exception message later without rebuild the solution.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: When you say `Business.config` you are referring to `Application Configuration File`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the **Business.config** file in Solution Explorer.

Select Properties and set Property **Copy to Output Directory** to `Copy if Newer` or `Copy always`.

This will copy configuration along with your business project dll (where ever you reference it in other C# project).

See image below:

[image]

Comment: My fault, because there 2 App.config. So this one replaces another. I have to rename to different config name.